# Javascript Google Custom search engine

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-custom-search

## Issue - Error

I get this error,

- Error: `CSE.js:130 Uncaught ReferenceError: google is not defined`

## Issue - Description

- However, if I use the chrome console in web tools, if `google.search....` is used, it works.
- not sure why google isn't loading in the context of my code, please help.

## Code

```js
    // Generate CSE Script
    let scr  = document.createElement('script'),
    head = document.head || document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
    scr.src = (document.location.protocol == 'https:' ? 'https:' : 'http:') + '//www.google.com/cse/cse.js?cx=' + cse_cx;
    scr.async = false; // optionally
    head.insertBefore(scr, head.firstChild);

    // Get Results Element
    let element = google.search.cse.element.getElement('searchresults-only0');
```

## after code executes, etc.

- doing this will work

[image]

Comment: is the google library imported?

Comment: is it loaded before you invoke it?

Comment: @MKant yes, it loaded via js then i try to execute my code, perhaps should i do some kind of onload  or ducment ready?

Comment: Run your last statement inside a `window.onload` wrapper or move it to the end of the body tag so the script has time to load.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to use the Search Element initialization callback in this case. Check out https://developers.google.com/custom-search/docs/element#init-callback

Answer (score 0):

So adding a "Delay" works,

I wrapped my code with a `setTimeout(function(){ /*CODE HERE*/ }, 1000);` after dynamically injecting the script.

Comment: While this workaround might "solve" the problem for you it is not a good idea to do it that way.  You should check if the library provides a way to figure out if it is loaded.

Comment: the delay is not a perfect solution to be honest though the code might work. What you should be doing is figure out if you have a handler in the library which gives you a way to execute the code afterwards the library is done loading